# How to change “Issued to” in Server certificates (for self-signed certificate)?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, sharepoint

[image]

I'm faced with an address mismatch in my Self-signed ssl certificate in my sharepoint site. I suspect I have to change the "Issued to" section, which is the common name in my server certificate to match that of my website's hostname. The Server certificates section can be found in my iis.

Since I cannot edit my certificate, how do I make a new self-signed certificate that matches my website address? Do I have to change the server name, or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify certificate contents, because they are digitally signed by an issuer. By changing any bit in the certificate you will make it totally invalid.

Instead, you have to generate new certificate signing request and provide correct names there. After that submit requests to your CA provider (in your case, it is DigiCert).

Comment: Can I change my server name or something like that? I'm trying to **create** a new self-signed certificate that matches my website. The cert is issued by the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're still getting the unsecure notification in your browser I suspect it isn't the common name you need to change.  Google Chrome and other browsers have switched over to using the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) while ignoring the common name.  You need to add your website's hostname and/or IP address in the Alternative Name field while applying for the certificate for the site to be recognized as secure by your web browser.  The certificate also needs to be signed by a trusted root certification authority that's listed in the TRCA store of the computer that's accessing the site.